# Mock Prototype Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am trying to mock the bean having scope prototype.

```
package com.aks.operation;
@Scope(value="prototype")
public class Operation{

 public int sum(int a,int b){
  return a+b;
 }

}

   @Service
       public class UseOperation{

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context;

       public void doOperation() throws Exception{
        Operation opr = context.getBean(Operation.class); // this will return the prototype instance
        ..
        ..
       }

       }
```

//Junit

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/app-context.xml" })
    @ActiveProfiles("DEV")
    @TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
            DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.aks.operation" })
    public class TestOperation{

     @InjectMocks
     private Operation operation;

    @Autowired
   private UseOperation useOperation;


    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception{
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      when(operation.sum(1,2)).thenReturn(3);
    }

     @Test
     public void doOperation() throws Exception{
       useOperation.doOperation();// this function will create the prototype instance, and that instance should be mine for which I did mocking
     }

    }
```

Please suggest what approach should I take to test the prototype instances.
It's the `context.getBean(Class<?>)` which is always returning me the new instances.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: What are you trying to test? Is the Operation class or the UseOperation class? If it is the UseOperation class than you are putting the wrong annotations. '@InjectMocks' must be on UseOperation, and '@Mock' must be on Operation.